# I wish to get a number from a range of 1 - 80 and if not in that range alert box appear

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I need some help with this. I have a form and some JavaScript but having trouble adding an alert box for when the wrong range is entered. I wish for an alert box to be displayed range out of 1-80 is entered like, for example, 81.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
// hide from old browsers

if (top != self) {
     top.location = self.location.href
}

// end script hiding
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// hide from non scripting browsers

function chooseRandom(form) {

var m = parseInt(form.lower.value);

var n = parseInt(form.upper.value) - m;

var output = Math.round(Math.random() * n) + m;

form.result.value = output;

}
// Clears the form

function clearForm(form) {

    form.upper.value="";

    form.lower.value="";

    form.upper.focus();

    form.upper.select();

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// calculates range from 1 - 80
var browName = navigator.appName;
var SiteID = 1;
var ZoneID = 80;
var browDateTime = (new Date()).getTime();
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of `round`, use `floor`. However, I can't see how the randomness is related to the range validation?

Comment: So add validation. Basic if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that is what you are looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chooseRandom(form) {
    var m = parseInt(form.lower.value);
    var n = parseInt(form.upper.value) - m;
    var output = Math.round(Math.random() * n) + m;
    form.result.value = output;
    }
    function clearForm(formId) {
    var form = document.getElementById(formId);
    form.upper.value = "";
    form.lower.value = "";
    form.result.value = "";
    form.upper.focus();
    }
    function chooseResult(formId) {
    var form = document.getElementById(formId);
    var upperVal = parseInt(form.upper.value);
    var lowerVal = parseInt(form.lower.value);
    if(isNaN(lowerVal) || isNaN(upperVal) || (lowerVal < 1) || (upperVal > 80) || (lowerVal >= upperVal)) {
        alert("Value(s) out of range, must be 1 <= lower < upper <= 80");
        clearForm(formId);
    }
    else {
        //          alert("Values ok");
        chooseRandom(form);
    }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="GET" action="">
    <p>Upper:</p><input id="upper" name="upper" type="number">
    <p>Lower:</p><input id="lower" name="lower" type="number">
    <p>Result:</p><input id="result" name="result" type="number">
    <button type="button" onclick="chooseResult('form1')">Choose result</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="clearForm('form1')">Clear form</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach an event handler to the inputs. This is much easier using a library like jQuery, you might want to investigate that. Here is a js solution though. The basic code flow is:

1. Get a high level event handler so we can detect changes on either input.
2. When the event trigger check and see if element has a certain validation class
3. Check that all values are acceptable. Warn user otherwise.

http://jsfiddle.net/B6E4s/

```
if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener('change', validate, false);
} else {
    document.body.attachEvent('change', validate); //for IE
}

function validate(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.className.match(/validateThis/)) {
        var lowerBoundVal = document.getElementById('lowerBound').value;
        var upperBoundVal = document.getElementById('upperBound').value;
        if (lowerBoundVal < 0) {
            alert('Enter # greater than 0');
        }
        if (upperBoundVal > 80) {
            alert('Enter # less than 81');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what I change in my code to get it working?

Comment: nvm i got it ty vm for your help mate